# .toColor() with supercharged Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to use the Supercharged package to be able to use a functionality that returns the color from hex string:

```
class _AppBarState extends State<AppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final red =  "#CAFAFE".toColor();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //backgroundColor: colorGreen,
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: red,
          ),[..........]
```

But it is not changing the default color of the Appbar.

Comment: Why did not you keep it simple? Set it as backgroundColor.

 // backgroundColor: red,

Answer (score 0):

First, `#cafafe` is not red. Second, I did not try but you can change the color name in lowercase.

```
    final red =  "#cafafe".toColor();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set a background colour of the AppBar, not decoration.

```
  backgroundColor: Color(
            int.tryParse("#CAFAFE".replaceFirst(RegExp(r'#'), '0xFF')))),
```